How can I save an HttpResponseMessage as binary?
From a GET API I receive JSON content with HttpResponseMessage. I wish to save that attachment as binary in my SQLite database. How can I do this and open it for the user to view?
{"Version":"1.1","Content":{"Headers":[{"Key":"Content-Disposition","Value":["attachment; filename=\"Formulaire de remise HDD_hors MINARM.pdf\""]},{"Key":"Content-Type","Value":["application/pdf"]}]},"StatusCode":200,"ReasonPhrase":"OK","Headers":[],"TrailingHeaders":[],"RequestMessage":null,"IsSuccessStatusCode":true}

When saving to database I'm getting it in JSON format:
var getFiles = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, $"{Constants.getTicketApi}/{data.Id}/Document?filename={filename}");
HttpResponseMessage fileresponse = await _httpClient.SendAsync(getFiles);
{
    if (fileresponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var filecontent = fileresponse.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;

        FilesDB file = new FilesDB
        {
            TicketId = data.Id,
            FileDescriptorID = fdId,
            Data = filecontent
        };

        await _context.SaveData(file);
    }
}
await _context.SaveData(filedescriptor);


you need to use await when calling async methods

used await but still getting the same thing '{"Version":"1.1","Content":{"Headers":[{"Key":"Content-Disposition","Value":["attachment; filename="Formulaire de remise HDD_hors MINARM.pdf""]},{"Key":"Content-Type","Value":["application/pdf"]}]},"StatusCode":200,"ReasonPhrase":"OK","Headers":[],"TrailingHeaders":[],"RequestMessage":null,"IsSuccessStatusCode":true}'

it doesn't appear that the body includes the attachment.  Without knowing more about the API you're using its difficult to say what you should do.  Looking at the call in Postman might give you more insight into what's contained in the response
